# Discrete Distribution question

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

[image]

Can anybody help out or give me a hint please? Thanks a lot!

Comment: **Hint:** Have a look at the [Central Limit Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_limit_theorem).

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** If you approximate the binomial coefficient $\binom{2n}{n}$ using Stirling's approximation, you get $\binom{2n}{n} \approx \frac{2^{2n}}{\sqrt{\pi n}}$, so that the probability of tossing a coin $2n$ times and getting exactly $n$ heads is about $\frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi n}}$.

This bit of information suggests that you show a correspondence between your problem and a single person tossing a coin $2n$ times and trying to get $n$ heads.